# How to remove an arrow from Google Maps geolocation marker (iOS)?

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation

How do you remove an arrow from Google Maps geolocation marker (iOS)?

This is an arrow I'm talking about

[image]

Comment: Not sure programmatically, but this thread has some info that might help you : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2528570?start=45&tstart=0

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want to remove that arrow *everywhere* in your app from *Google Maps SDK*, it might be easiest to modify asset in *GoogleMaps.framework*.

Just navigate (`cd`) to `GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/` and notice the following files:

- GMSSprites-0-1x.png
- GMSSprites-0-2x.png
- GMSSprites-0-3x.png

If you open these files, you can notice the arrow is there. So just edit directly in the asset by replacing arrow by *nothing* (transparent pixels).

---

Note: I haven't test it myself and this is not tested solution, but I believe it should work.

Disclaimer: I'm not sure, but I think this modification might violate Terms & Conditions for using the SDK. I don't get any responsibility for such modification, it's your call...

Comment: Thanks! I will test it today, I think it should work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with current version of the SDK (1.9.1), and actually there is an open issue with this request: Look [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5143&q=label%3AApiType-IosSDK&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal).

As a work around, you can hide the default button with:

`_map.myLocationEnabled = NO;`

Then create a custom GMSMarker

```
 GMSMarker *pointMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:currentPosition];
 pointMarker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage"];
 pointMarker.map = _map;
```

And change the position of it using a CLLocationManager, so it always show the current position. It's a bit tricky but is the only way, I could think, that you can achieve this. If you need a more complete example let me know.